# Custom Dialog not cancelling even after setting cancellable true

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a custom ActivityIndicator defined as this

```
public class ActivityIndicator extends Dialog
{
    private ImageView progress;
    private ImageView bottomProgress;

    private int type = INDICATOR_SIMPLE;

    public static final int INDICATOR_SIMPLE = 0;
    public static final int INDICATOR_BOTTOM = 1;

    public ActivityIndicator(Context context, int theme, int type)
    {
        super(context, theme);
        this.type = type;
        onCreate(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.dialog_indicator);

        progress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
        bottomProgress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottomProgress);

        if(type == INDICATOR_BOTTOM)
        {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        else if(type == INDICATOR_SIMPLE)
        {
            bottomProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
        this.setCancelable(false);
    }

    @Override
    public void show()
    {
        progress.clearAnimation();
        bottomProgress.clearAnimation();

        if(type == INDICATOR_BOTTOM)
        {
            progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotating_img);
                    bottomProgress.startAnimation(anim);
                }
            },400);
        }

        if(type == INDICATOR_SIMPLE)
        {
            bottomProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
            {
                @Override
                public void run()
                {
                    Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getContext(), R.anim.rotating_img);
                    progress.startAnimation(anim);
                }
            },400);
        }
        super.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismiss()
    {
        super.dismiss();
        progress.clearAnimation();
        bottomProgress.clearAnimation();
    }
}
```

In my activity I initialize it as:

```
        indicator = new ActivityIndicator(this, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent_NoTitleBar_Fullscreen, ActivityIndicator.INDICATOR_SIMPLE);
```

Now as seen in code , default style cancelable is false.

However at some point i do want to put it cancelable , here is my code:

```
        indicator.setCancelable(true);
        indicator.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog)
            {
                finish();
            }
        });
indicator.show();
```

When I try to press the back button, nothing happens, the `dialog` doesn't cancel nor the cancel listener. What is wrong here? Why is it not cancelling automatically on back key pressed

Comment: Instead of `finish()` try `dismiss()` or `dialog.dismiss()`

Comment: @Clairvoyant that's the point.. where to call these :) Cancel listener not working. Back pressed just does nothing

Comment: sorry ihaven't read the whole of your question

Comment: You shouldn't be hacking the code to fix the problem. Your problem lies with the onCreate. Have a look at my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't `Override` `onCreate()`. That `onCreate(null)` method that you invoke is what's screwing up your code. Rather use an initializer pattern to initialize the `Dialog`.

If you change your `onCreate` to an `initialize()` and invoke that from the constructor the code will work.

Look at the following.

```
public ActivityIndicator(Context context, int theme, int type)
{
    super(context, theme);
    this.type = type;

    initialize();
}

protected void initialize()
{
    setContentView(R.layout.dialog_indicator);
    setCancelable(false);

    progress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.progress);
    bottomProgress = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.bottomProgress);

    if(type == INDICATOR_BOTTOM)
    {
        progress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
    else if(type == INDICATOR_SIMPLE)
    {
        bottomProgress.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please comment your seton cancellabel and use below code and check.

```
indicator.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK){
            finish();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is great answer, however it still doesn't answer my question, why this behavior?

Comment: This isn't a viable solution. It might solve the issue but it's a hack.

Answer (score 0):

When you are creating an instance of `ActivityIndicator`, in the `OnCreate` method, `setCancelable` is set to false.

Try removing that..

Comment: But he is setting it as true when creating object.

Answer (score 0):

Got you problem just change your constructor like below and you would get your cancel listner called:

```
public ActivityIndicator(Context context, int theme, int type, boolean isCancelable)
    {
        super(context, theme);
        this.type = type;
        onCreate(null);
        this.setCancelable(isCancelable); //setcancelable here on the basis of boolean value and remove setcancelable from onCreate()
    }
```

Call the constructor with one more argument which is boolean true/false

**Note:** Don't forget to remove `setCancelable()` from `onCreate()` method.